# Awk command to parse grep

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have the following command whose output is shown below,is there a way to write an awk command to parse the current output and just print only the ones shown in the "expected output" field below?

```
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit query --commit-message --files --current-patch-set status:open project:platform/vendor/company/radio branch:master |grep refs
```

Current output:-

```
ref: refs/changes/26/206026/1
ref: refs/changes/25/206025/1
ref: refs/changes/22/206022/1
```

Desired output:-

```
206026
206025
206022
```

Comment: There is almost never any need to combine use `grep` in conjunction with `awk`.  `grep foo | awk '{cmd}'` is the same as `awk '/foo/{cmd}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you asked by `awk` but maybe you can try it with `cut`:

```
cut -f4 -d"/"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' input
```

Another thing is, you can remove the grep and use awk directly:

```
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit query     \
          --commit-message --files        \
          --current-patch-set status:open \
          project:platform/vendor/company/radio branch:master |
    awk -F'/' '/refs/ {print $(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: Remember that `awk` can do the 'grep', for example: `... | awk -F'/' '/refs/ {print $(NF-1)}'`

Answer (score 1):

Or how about just using `grep`:

```
$ ... | grep -Po '(?<=ref: refs/changes/[0-9]{2}/)[0-9]+'
206026
206025
206022
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep search_string /directory/filename | cut -f1 -d':'
```

grep for a search string from a directory of files (i.e. *.c, for a list of c files).

`grep include */*.c` --- in addition to returning a list of c files from all subdirectories that contain the keyword "include". this command output will also contain the entire line on which the search string is located.

For example `./tmp/readline-6.2:# include < stdlib.h>` this is output from the grep command - there might be several lines of output each containing the "include" keyword.

To get just the filename from this output:

```
grep include /.c | cut -f1 -d':'
```